# Call VBA function from Excel - Find in a selected column on a selected sheet

Tags: vba, user-defined-functions

Looking for some expert advise on Excel VBA. I have written a small piece of code that selects a column in a specific sheet and perform a find/search on the selection. When I call the function from Excel it doesn't find anything as the Range value returned by find is empty. However when I run it directly within developer window it works fine.

Please note I'm aware same could be done using existing Excel macros. But I don't want to use them for a reason. Hope you understand.

Here is the code;

```
Function MYFIND(x As Range) As Integer
Dim Cell As Range
Worksheets("Sheet4").Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Set Cell = Selection.Find(What:=x.Value, searchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

If Cell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "search item " & x.Value & " not found in " & ActiveSheet.Name
Else
    MsgBox "Found item " & Cell.Row
End If
MYFIND = 0 
End Function
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Your 'Function' name is 'MYFIND' but then, in your code you don't use it in any form. Also, very rarely you use a 'MsgBos' inside a 'Function' that returns a value.What exactly are you trying to achieve ? Perhaps you can share a screen-shot of your data, and desired result

Comment: Hey Shai, I corrected the return variable name (edited the code above). It was a copy paste error. I set MYFIND = 0 which always return 0 but use MsgBox instead for testing purpose. When run the code I'm expecting to see the message "found item [row-num]".

Comment: Idea is once I get the code working to find what I need then i would set the value to the return variable which would set the return value in the cell of the excel sheet. I call the user defined function (UDF) from excel using =MYFIND(G2) where "G2" cell consist of the text I search for in the selection.

Comment: Just a quick tip: use `Debug.Print` instead of `MsgBox`, saves a click and isn't blocking.It will output to the Immediate window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the UDF below, try as much as you can to avoid using `Select` and `Selection.

***Modified UDF***

```
Function MYFIND(x As Range) As Long

Dim Rng As Range
Dim Cell As Range

' set the range, never use select or selection
Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet4").Columns("A:A")
Set Cell = Rng.Find(What:=x.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlWhole, searchDirection:=xlNext)

If Cell Is Nothing Then
    MYFIND = 0 ' returns 0 if not found
Else
    MYFIND = Cell.Row
End If

End Function
```

Then, call your UDF from your worksheet:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Shai. Using range did work. Just for my knowledge, what's the problem with select and selection ?

Comment: @JasonNanay read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 0):

Jason,

How about this?

```
Option Explicit

Function MYFIND(y As String) As Integer

Dim Cell      As Range
Dim GLAccount As Long
Dim x         As Range

Set x = Range(y)

Set Cell = Sheet4.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=x.Value, searchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

If Cell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "search item " & x.Value & " not found in " & ActiveSheet.Name
Else
    MsgBox "Found item " & Cell.Row
End If

  MYFIND = Cell.Row()

End Function
```

Call as:

```
=MyFind("E1")
```

Where E1 contains the value you're looking for.
I set up letters a-f in col A of Sheet4 (used the code name in the code) and it returned 3 as c is in row 3.

HTH

Comment: Thanks @RetiredGeek for the suggestion. It is strange that I get value error when use this code. Perhaps because I'm calling it from "Sheet5" ?

Comment: Jason, I was calling it from sheet1 so you calling it from sheet5 shouldn't be a problem. As long as Column A values were on sheet4.